# Using Waypoint jQuery Plugin to trigger FadeTo

Tags: jquery-waypoints, fadeto

I am attempting to use the Waypoint plugin to make one element fadeTo 50%  when another "trigger" element is 25% from the top when you are scrolling down and fadeTo 100% when the "trigger" element is 25% from the top and you are scrolling up.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#trigger').waypoint(function(direction) {
                if (direction === "down") {
                    $('#background-holder').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
                }
                if (direction === "up") {
                    $('#background-holder').fadeTo('slow', 1);
                }, { offset: '25%' });
        });
```

Currently, the code that I have above isn't doing anything. Is there something that I'm missing? I'm not an expert in using jQuery, but I've never not been able to get some kind of response from my code.

Comment: OK, so what's your question?  Is it behaving differently than you expected?

Comment: Sorry, the question is that this isn't working at all. Is there something completely wrong with my code, or is there an aspect of working with Waypoint that I missed?

Comment: So what happens now as you scroll down past the intended trigger point?